# how can make search form in ci?

Tags: php, codeigniter, search

I have search form to search value in my db that price is varchar in my table.I want to search a value that is between min and max that I get this value from my form.and it can't find the any result.and always show 404 page.
thanks for your help.

my view

```
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/search">

     <div class="col-md-3">
     <input name="min" class="form-control" id="min">

    </input> 

     </div>

   <div class="col-md-3">
     <input name="max" class="form-control" id="max">

    </input> 

     </div>
 </form>
```

my controller:

```
 public function search()
   {
        $jdata = array();
        $jdata=array(
        'min' => $this->input->post('min'),
        'max' => $this->input->post('max')
        );

        $this->load->model('selectallmodel');

        $data['res']=$this->selectallmodel->get_search($jdata);         

   }
```

my model:

```
    function get_search($jdata) 
 {
    $this->db->select('mytable.*');
    $this->db->from('mytable');
    $this->db->where('mytable.price>',$jdata['min']);
    $this->db->where('mytable.price<',$jdata['max']);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query -> num_rows() == 0)
    {
        redirect('404');
    }
    else    return $query->result_array();

    }
   }
```

Comment: Where is your `get_search()` function in model file??

Comment: Use  `$this->db->where('mytable.price>',$jdata['price']);
    $this->db->where('mytable.price<',$jdata['price']);` in your query

Comment: @Zoee
May be it is for no data found from Database.
Have you checked with all cases?
Have print returned Array?

Comment: I checked it.I have problem with min and max that I dont know type of them(I get them from my search form) and my price that type of my price is varchar.can I compare different type???

Comment: I have this error::: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `mytable`.`price` > '50000000' AND `mytable`.`price` < '55000000'' at line 2

Comment: @Zoee
Remove single and double from value.

Comment: it show me always 404 bacause I don't put space between mytable.price and <. and now it is solved. :)